# python database add +1 to a column

Tags: python, mysql, sql, database, sql-update

i want to increment a column in my database , how can i do that ?

```
if result[0] is True and result[1] != "":  # a win
               your_details["score"] = your_details["score"] + 1
               lbl_status["text"] = "Game over, You won! You(" + str(your_details["score"]) + ") - " \
                                                                                              "" + opponent_details[
                                        "name"] + "(" + str(opponent_details["score"]) + ")"

               req = 'UPDATE INTO users("nb_win") VALUES("nb_win + 1")'
               infos = your_details["score"]
               print(infos)

               try:
                   cursor.execute(req, infos)
                   db_connection.commit()

               except mysql.Error as err:
                   print(err)
```

```
def connect():
    global your_details
    if len(ent_name.get()) < 1:
        tk.messagebox.showerror(title="ERROR!!!", message="You MUST enter your first name <e.g. John>")
    else:
        your_details["name"] = ent_name.get()
        print(ent_name.get())
        connect_to_server(ent_name.get())

        req = 'INSERT INTO users(user_name) VALUES("'+ ent_name.get()+'")'
        infos = ent_name
```

If someone can help me, thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an `update` statement. Assuming that the primary key of your table is `id`, that would be:

```
UPDATE users SET nb_win = nb_win + 1 WHERE user_name = ?
```

The `?` in the query should be replaced with the `id` of the row whose `nb_win` you want to increment.

Comment: I try to add ```req = 'UPDATE users SET nb_win = nb_win + 1 WHERE id = ("'+your_details["name"]+'")'``` , but didn't work. I update my post with where I add the username of the user but it's in a function. I don't know if i can retrieve that.

Comment: @nico31780: maybe you want `req = "UPDATE users SET nb_win = nb_win + 1  WHERE user_name = '" + your_details["name"] + "'"`?

Comment: Thank you it worked ! You can update your answer so i can accept it :)